# Mongodb aggregate group variables

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

In the code below I would like to use the final 'total_pax' (sum of passengers for a given origin destination) as input to calculate the ratio in  es['pax'] / total_pax 
Can I do this in one query like below ?

```
    for i, es in enumerate(External_Segment.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'provider': 'ukcaa'}},
    {'$group': group1}], cursor={}, allowDiskUse=True), 1):

        cursor = Routes.aggregate([{'$match': {
            'year_month': year_month,
            'leg_origin': origin,
            'leg_destination': destination,
            'record_ok': True,
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'origin': '$leg_origin',
                'destination': '$leg_destination',
            },

            'total_pax': {
                '$sum': '$passengers'
            },

            'ratio_ukcaa_pax': {
             es['pax'] / total_pax  
            }

        }
         'pax_after_ukcaa_ratio': {
                    passengers * ratio_ukcaa_ratio
            }

    }])
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you add a source document?  There is average function avaliable which could be used here

Comment: Or you could check $let operator used in $project phase